# why does every process(or any address space) has its own page table?

Tags: operating-system

1. Why does every process (or any address space) have its own page table?

   - I think that if we use a single page table for all processes, then a process can access the address apace of other processes so we need a separate page table for each process. This means the pages which actually belong to a particular process will be valid and all other pages which belong to some other's address space will be marked invalid. Am I correct?
   - If yes, then why didn't we add one more field as "process ID" to the page table to distinguish the address space of every process?
   - If not, why does every process (or any address space) have its own page table?
2. How can multilevel paging reduce the size of the page table?

   - Because we added some more page tables (in multilevel paging) as overhead, and the actual page table is also in main memory
3. Suppose we did 3 levels of paging as 1 (closer to CPU)->2->3; so we have three page tables for each level. What information is included in each page table? I am worried about 3rd level page table which contains the actual frame number where data resides. Now which page tables are used by processes?

   - All??? Then the 3rd level page table which contains the actual frames should be of the same size as the original page table (without multilevel) because it must have entries for all frames which are used by physical memory too.

Comment: Please state a real question (without answer options). Maybe you should also go to serverfault not stackoverflow - since it is operating system related.

Comment: 1)Why does every process (or any address space) have its own page table?

Comment: 2)How can multilevel paging reduce the size of the page table?

Comment: 3)Suppose we did 3 levels of paging as 1 (closer to CPU)->2->3; so we have three page tables for each level. What information is included in each page table? I am worried about 3rd level page table which contains the actual frame number where data resides. Now which page tables are used by processes?

Comment: Processes have their own page table so they can be swapped in and out of main memory.  Also, like you said, to have its own private address space.

Comment: means the page table entry for a page (for a particular process) will be valid only if the corresponding frame belongs to a process ? and all other entries will be invalid?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct in saying that one of the reason behind separate page tables is security concerns. Paging interface is exposed by hardware to the OS. The hardware doesn't understand what is a process? Process semantics is part of the OS design.For this reason we can't add process ID to page tables. You can look at hardware manuals to learn how paging works. Yes you are right that multilevel page doesn't help in reducing size of the page table. In my opinion the hardware requirement is top level page table must be always mapped in the memory. If there is only one level then you always need to map all the page table pages even if they are not used. This might be a reason why hardware exposes multiple level page tables.